# How do I overcome tracebacks while importing requests-html module for webscraping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-module, thonny

I'm getting a LONG list of errors when running a short script based on import requests-html. I'd like to understand why the error occurs, and learn how to overcome it.

This is my code:

```
import requests_html

from requests_html import HTML
with open('disinformation_index.html') as html_file:
    source = html_file.read()
    html = HTML(html=source)
 
print(html.text)
```

This is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jp/webscraping_with_requests_html.py", line 5, in <module>
    import requests_html
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pyppeteer
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pyppeteer.launcher import connect, launch, executablePath  # noqa: E402
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pyppeteer.browser import Browser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/browser.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pyppeteer.connection import Connection
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/connection.py", line 12, in <module>
    import websockets
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .auth import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/auth.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .server import HTTPResponse, WebSocketServerProtocol
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/server.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .protocol import WebSocketCommonProtocol
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 18, in <module>
    from typing import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'Deque'
```

*I'm running the code on the Thonny IDE, and I have my interpreter set to Python 3.6.0. I'm on Mac Catalina.

It looks as if the fail comes from sub-packages in the requests-html library. I'm too new to coding to be sure, but the code does seem to access the requests-html module, but then breaks while trying to read some elements of it.

Is that what's happening? Is there a way to overcome this?

Is the issue with my interpreter (3.6.0)? I've read that requests-html is supported only in 3.6, so I assumed I'd have to set that in Thonny as my interpreter.

The code snippet is from a Corey Schafer webscraping tutorial on YouTube, here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6fIbtFB46g

It's been suggested that a post involving editing the protocol.py file to tell it to import "Deque" from Collections, instead of from Typing (where it's called from in the 'native' version of 3.6) could be the solution.

I just tried that, and failed.

This is my new error message, after editing protocol.py (once again, the fail is 'can't import Deque).

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/joelprestonsmith/webscraping_with_requests_html.py", line 7, in 
from requests_html import HTML
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 9, in 
import pyppeteer
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/**init**.py", line 30, in 
from pyppeteer.launcher import connect, launch, executablePath  # noqa: E402
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py", line 24, in 
from pyppeteer.browser import Browser
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/browser.py", line 13, in 
from pyppeteer.connection import Connection
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/connection.py", line 12, in 
import websockets
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/**init**.py", line 3, in 
from .auth import *
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/auth.py", line 15, in 
from .server import HTTPResponse, WebSocketServerProtocol
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/server.py", line 49, in 
from .protocol import WebSocketCommonProtocol
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 13, in 
from collections import Deque
ImportError: cannot import name 'Deque'

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'Deque'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60011092/importerror-cannot-import-name-deque)

Comment: This is a slightly clearer suggestion about a solution: "you need to change /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py file import deque from collections instead of type"

Comment: There are several reasons why the suggested answer doesn't work. It's for a cloud-based version of Python. I'm running mine from harddrive. The suggested solution says that it's possible "that the version of Python you're running on Heroku doesn't have typing.Deque." 

I'm not running Heroku, and I've verified that there is a call for Deque in the protocol.py file. 

The original protocol.py code (in part) is: 

from typing import (
    Any,
    AsyncIterable,
    AsyncIterator,
    Awaitable,
    Deque,
    Dict,
    Iterable,
    List,
    Optional,
    Union,
    cast,
)